# Scrollable tkinter canvas with widgets is only filling half the frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I tried doing the scrollable canvas method in tkinter but the canvas is only filling half the screen starting from the top down, it is filling the screen to the sides.

```
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default = "icon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "name")
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, "1024x576")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Frame1, Frame2, ...):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Frame1)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Frame2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", tags="self.frame")
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

    for i in range(n):
        "a bunch of widgets".grid(column = 0, row = i)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: This code isn't runnable as posted. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: `Canvas` has some size and `grid()` respects this size. If you use `frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)` instead of `frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= "nsew")` then it resize Frame2 to full window.

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid` doesn't resize widgets automatically.

You may inform `container` (as parent for `frame` which use `frame.grid`) which row(s) and column(s) in grid can use more space and resize widgets. (different rows/columns may have different `weight`)

```
    container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    for F in (Frame2, ):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
```

or you can use `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.grid()`

```
    for F in (Frame2, ):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```

Comment: The configure method worked perfectly. Thank you very much.
The pack method broke my application because I'm also packing the container.